# Element is not displayed, even then size showing is 1 in selenium. see code I have used

Tags: java, selenium

There's a tab that opens when I click on that.  I am checking before clicking whether it's open or not.  So for that I'm using visibility of an element of that tab when that gets opened.

I have tried both:

1. `isDisplayed()`
2. `findElements().size()>0`

It's not open so that element is not visible so it must be returning size 0 or `isDisplayed` "false";

```
int elements = this.config.getDriver().findElements(panelElement).size();
```

It's returning `1`, where `panelElement` is the element that is inside that tab.
When I search that on inspection I get one match but that's not visible.

I have also used `isDisplayed()`.

```
new WebElementWrapper(this.config, panelElement).isDisplayed();
```

But it is returning `true`.

Comment: @Brian thank you Brian for the modification. :).. 
Is there any way to do what I have asked ??

Comment: What does the markup for the page look like?

Comment: they are using prime faces framework